# WAR file deploy works on one machine but not the other

Tags: maven, tomcat, tomcat7, war, web-deployment

I have installed Tomcat using the exact same method on two different machines. Both use the Windows Service Installer found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)

I generated a WAR file be doing `mvn clean install -X`. I then copied the WAR file to the two other Windows machines and attempted to deploy through both the Web App Manager and by placing the WAR file in the \webapps folder. I am able to start the app on one machine but not the other. Again, the Tomcat installations are exactly the same and I have tried reinstalling Tomcat on the machine where the app did not start but was still unable to start my app afterwards.

Here is the tomcat7-stdout.log from the machine that where the app works:

```
2017-07-21 11:58:28 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
```

Here is the tomcat7-stdout.log from the machine that where the app does NOT work. There is a NullPointerException showing that something is missing but I am not sure what. The dependencies in the Tomcat 7.0\libs folder are the same between the two machines.

```
INFO  [2017-07-21 23:45:13,343] be.fluid_it.tools.dropwizard.box.bridge.JEEBridge: Dummy start Jetty server ...
INFO  [2017-07-21 23:45:13,354] com.sample.sam.core.FrameworkManager: Loading OSGI framework.
INFO  [2017-07-21 23:45:13,375] com.sample.sam.core.FrameworkManager: Starting OSGI framework.
WARN  [2017-07-21 23:45:13,919] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED com.sample.sam.core.FrameworkManager@172ac2a5: java.lang.NullPointerException
! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
! at com.sample.sam.core.FrameworkManager.loadFrameworkBundles(FrameworkManager.java:98) ~[sam-portal-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at com.sample.sam.core.FrameworkManager.start(FrameworkManager.java:132) ~[sam-portal-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
! at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.JettyManaged.doStart(JettyManaged.java:27) ~[dropwizard-lifecycle-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
! at com.sample.sam.PortalWebApplication.contextInitialized(PortalWebApplication.java:65) [classes/:na]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:683) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) [servlet-api.jar:na]
! at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) [catalina.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.79]
! at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.79]
! at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
! at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
! at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.79]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
INFO  [2017-07-21 23:45:14,035] com.sample.sam.core.FrameworkManager: Stopping OSGI framework.
INFO  [2017-07-21 23:45:14,112] com.sample.sam.core.FrameworkManager: OSGI framework stopped.
INFO  [2017-07-21 23:45:14,112] com.sample.sam.PortalWebApplication: Deregistering JDBC driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver@247eef58
```

Any advice on why the exact same Tomcat install and WAR file works on one machine but not the other would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you checked for any memory leaks ?

Comment: @SachinChavan How do I check that?

Comment: Additionally, I compared the \lib folder and the jars between the two machines are exactly the same